# Send emulator console commands during Espresso test

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-espresso

Google explains how to control many parameters of an Android emulator, like the current charge of the battery, the sensor input and so on here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console.html .

I would like to create an Espresso test that changes these parameters of an emulator during a test, is this possible? I know that there is the following method:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation
    .executeShellCommand("someShellCommand")
```

This method can be called during a test, but for changing system parameters of an emulator I first have to login via `telnet localhost 5554` and only then can I manipulate the emulator parameters like, for example, so: `power capacity 30`, which changes the power of the battery to 30%. How can I do this during an Espresso test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation()
    .executeShellCommand("dumpsys battery set level 30");
```

to change the battery level. Other values or settings may require different commands.

**Note: It is your responsibility to close the returned file descriptor once you are done reading.**

Comment: If somebody is using this, be sure to call `.close()` on the object that is returned by `executeShellCommand()`. Otherwise subsequent tests will fail.

Comment: As of API 18 looks like you need to use the getter: `.getUiAutomation()`.